# How to modify values in delimiter text file in unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have a huge file with delimited value with '~' example

abc~poi~123~jijda~123~abc

Requirement is to replace the values at 3rd occurrence (which is 123 in our case) to be replaced with 111.

I used the below command

> awk -F '~' -v OFS='~' '$3 == "123" {$3 = "111"} 1 ' file.txt > Newfile.txt

this works for manually created file but when it the file was created using utf-8 encoding it doesn't work. Can some one help on this. Thanks!

Comment: _it doesn't work_ Please be more specific. How did it not work?

Comment: Run `awk -F'~' '{print "-----" ORS NR ORS $0 ORS NF ORS; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print "\t" i, $i} NR==2{exit}' file.txt | cat -Ev` and copy/paste the output into your question so we can see what a couple of lines of your input looks like.

Comment: *file was created using utf-8 encoding it doesn't work* how exactly such file is created?

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 should be no problem.

```
# SO71048003.awk
BEGIN {
  FS = OFS = "~"
  out = "Newfile.txt"
}

{
  if ($3 == "123")
    $3 = "111"
  print $0 > out
}
```

Call:

```
awk -f SO71048003.awk file.txt
=> Newfile.txt with content:
abc~poi~111~jijda~123~abc
```

Comment: Question to the OP: Do you want to replace all values in the third field with "111" or only if the value is "123"? Your code shows only if the value is "123" but your text "to replace the values at 3rd occurrence (which is 123 in our case)". This is also a bit unclear. If all values are meant, of course the answer by Carlos is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your `awk` code with some changes:

```
awk -F'~' -v OFS='~' '{$3=111} 1' file
abc~poi~111~jijda~123~abc
```

- we assign to `$3` the `111` value.